# Handling and printing exceptions with SML

Tags: exception, sml, mlton

I have a code that looks quite like:

```
ignore
  (f ())
  handle
    AssertionError msg         => (print ("assertion error: " ^ msg ^ "\n"); ())
    | _ (* other exceptions *) => (print ("exception raised\n"); ())
```

But I need to print the generic exception message (with `exnMessage`?).

How do I catch the `_` exception in order to get and print its message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match the exception with a name instead of `_` and use `exnMessage`:

```
- (hd ([]: string list)) handle e => exnMessage e;
val it = "Empty" : string
```

Comment: Wow! I swear I thought I tried that yet.  It works, thanks!